# React native - React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:'getAllPost'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.",

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new in react native and try to call two api from `useEffect` but it give me this error every time `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAllPost'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Here is my code

```
export default function Home({navigation}) {
  const [arrCat, setArrCat] = useState([]);
  const [arrPost, setArrPost] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoding] = useState(false);

  function getAllCategory() {
    setLoding(true);
    let apiResponse = ApiManager.GET('category/all', [], 'GET');
    apiResponse
      .then(response => {
        let responseJson = response[1];
        let status = response[0];
        setLoding(false);
        let message =
          responseJson.message != null
            ? response.message
            : 'Something went wrong';
        if (status === 200) {
          setArrCat([...responseJson.data]);
          getAllPost();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (message != null) {
            Toast.showWithGravity(message, Toast.LONG, Toast.BOTTOM);
          }
        }, 120);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        Toast.showWithGravity(error, Toast.LONG, Toast.BOTTOM);
        setTimeout(function() {
          setLoding(false);
        }, 60);
      });
  }
  function getAllPost() {
    GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
    })
      .then(location => {
        console.log(location);
        const dictData = {
          lat: '-37.81400200-33.865143', //location.latitude,
          lang: '144.9546943', //location.longitude,
          record_count: '0',
        };
        console.log(dictData);
        let apiResponse = ApiManager.POST(
          'post/getRecommendedPost',
          dictData,
          'POST',
        );
        apiResponse
          .then(response => {
            let responseJson = response[1];
            let status = response[0];
            if (status === 200) {
              console.log(responseJson);
              setArrPost(oldValue => [...oldValue, ...responseJson.data]);
              console.log(arrPost);
            } else {
              // console.error(responseJson);
              Toast.showWithGravity(
                responseJson.message,
                Toast.LONG,
                Toast.BOTTOM,
              );
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // console.error(error);
            Toast.showWithGravity(error.message, Toast.LONG, Toast.BOTTOM);
            // setTimeout(function() {
            //   setLoding(false);
            // }, 60);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // const {code, message} = error;
        // console.warn(code, message);
        Toast.showWithGravity(error.message, Toast.LONG, Toast.BOTTOM);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Home screen mounted');
    getAllCategory();
    // getAllPost();
  }, []);

  return ( ....)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear if there's actually a problem with your code as you haven't specified what your expected result/behavior should be. I take it the linter isn't complaining about `getAllCategory`? Have you tried adding `getAllPost` to the dependencies? Perhaps try `useCallback` and memoize `getAllPost`?

Comment: @DrewReese I am just learning react native from last 1 month and I am mobile developer so i have not good idea about the useCallBack and all the things so will you please share some example. I have requirement like first i need to get all the category and then need to get all post.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you need to add `getAllPost` to the hook's dependency array, or remove the dependency array entirely. I doubt you want the effect to run every render, so you could try adding it. Does adding it resolve the warning? Does the code still do what you want it to do?

Comment: @DrewReese Are you sure it will run on every render? An empty dependency array means it's going to be the same as `componentDidMount`. So it will run only one time. Which is maybe what the OP wants.

Comment: @AndreiOlar yes, if you don't pass a dependency array the hook will run every render.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, if you don't pass one. But if you pass an empty array, that's a different story.

Comment: @AndreiOlar OP *is* passing an empty dependency array and react is warning them that the `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getAllPost'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.` If they remove the dependency array the hook **will run** every render, which I pointed out probably *isn't* the behavior they were going for. From here there are a few options: add `getAllPost` to dependency array, memoize `getAllPast` function so reference is stable, or add an `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` override for the warning.

Comment: You said: `The error is pretty clear, you need to add getAllPost to the hook's dependency array, or remove the dependency array entirely.` No, there is the 3rd option, where the dependencies array can be left empty and the effect will only run once. That's all I wanted to point out. :)

Comment: Can anybody suggest me any solution for this?

Comment: Thanks everyone i just change my code converted into class and bingo. it's working properly

Comment: @chiragshah There's no reason really to not be able to attain the same behavior with a functional component and hooks. Curious, did you try either of the solutions that were suggested, here and in the error?

Comment: @DrewReese as i told you I am very much new in this language so i try but not able to success so I converted to class